# React component to display crypto price live data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, finance, cryptocurrency

Wondering which React component I can use to display live crypto data fetched from a dex.
I want to be able to filter by price, market cap or percentage.
I see the exactly same component being used on different tools (https://dexscreener.com/, https://www.dextools.io/, https://www.geckoterminal.com/).
Anyone knows the name of it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1zHW.png)

Chart.js and tradingview component , they are not the same.

Comment: They all seem to be using the Advanced Chart TradingView widget. https://www.tradingview.com/widget-docs/widgets/charts/advanced-chart/ (enable "Show drawing tools bar") to get most of the left side bar.